# Enter user details into database after registration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to register a user using C# in asp.net and then put their details into my database. Everything seems to work fine but the details don't go into the database.
Here's what I have so far:

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "users");

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, title, gname, sname, dob, address, suburb, state, postcode, phone, email) VALUES (@UserName, @Title1, @FirstName, @FamilyName, @DateOfBirth, @Address, @Suburb, @State, @Postcode, @Phone, @Email)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Email.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title1", Title1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilyName", FamilyName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suburb", Suburb.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", Postcode.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text.Trim());
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowCount > 0)
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Success. New User Registered";
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

and on the web.config page I have the connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabaseConnection.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: No, it all looks like it works normally, but then the details don't appear in the database

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Are you been thrown out the scope if any condition didn't meet?

Comment: Yeah, I have. Not being thrown out, all appears to work perfectly. So I wonder if there's a problem with the connection to the database?

Comment: `rowCount` returns bit as 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Profile the sql server while running this code and see what statements are actually getting run.

Comment: You are using **LocalDB** i.e. your mdf file is located inside App_Data. Just for starter please do check is your file in open state I mean you are currently viewing the table from **SQL Server Object Explorer**.

Comment: Oh, ok so when I'm looking at the table from SQL Server Object Explorer, it says that database can't open.

Comment: Also, how do I profile the sql server while running the code? Sorry, I'm pretty new to vb

Comment: **Profile** the sql server ? It seems a very heavy term to me.

Comment: are you able to use the database otherwise? i.e. are selects and other inserts/updates in the application working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string isn't specifying a catalog - ie the database to use

for example, my test database reads:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add     name="WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.mbcConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Data Source is the server location, catalog is the database within that server